# ExtJS mask a TreePanel without toolbar

Tags: javascript, extjs

Im trying to mask a tree panel without the toolbar so that the user can keep typing as the panel is masked. This seems to be harder than I thought so some suggestions would be great!

Although its prob not necessary, Here is my (stripped down) base tree panel:

```
Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    id:'quicksearch_panel',
    root:{
        nodeType:'async',   
        preloadChildren:false       
    },
    loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
        dataUrl:'...',        
        baseParams:{}       
    }),
    tbar:['Quicksearch:', {     
        xtype:'textfield',
        id:'quicksearch_combo',
        emptyText: 'search...',
        listeners:{
            keyup:{buffer:400, fn:function(field, e) {

                     // Mask Panel and not Combo HERE
                }}     
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to mask the `body` of the TreePanel? The Element `body` is an element in all components that inherits `Panel`, and the Toolbar is in fact out of this `body` element so you probably could just mask the `body`, your toolbar will be out of the masking overlay.

Try this:

```
var tree = Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    //......
    tbar: ['Quicksearch:', {
        xtype:'textfield',
        emptyText: 'search...',
        enableKeyEvents: true, //you need this for key events
        listeners:{
            keyup:{
                buffer:400,
                fn:function(field, e) {
                     tree.body.mask();

                     //When the searching done, unmask it
                     //tree.body.unmask();
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Do update us if it works :)

Comment: Thanks Lionel that worked a treat! I was trying .getEl('body') which seemed to mask the whole thing.

Comment: No problem :). `this.body` is quite useful for me to mask most panel related components, like `Window`, which you might want to mask your body only, but not the cross button/button row on the floating Window.